# Changing a word into 3 equal arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm working on a project where I take a word and split it into 3 arrays but the arrays must be of equal length. Here is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
String password = JOptionPane.showinputdialogue("Password: );
split = password;

    final int mid = split.length() / 3;
    final int third = split.length() / 3 * 2;
    String[] parts = {
        split.substring(0, mid),
        split.substring(mid, third),
        split.substring(mid),};

    part1 = parts[0];
    part2 = parts[1];
    part3 = parts[2];
```

Thanks for the help
~Jay

Comment: what happens if password.length % 3 > 0?

Comment: The last part should be `split.substring(third)` and not `split.substring(mid)`.

Comment: Can we assume your password length is always divisible by 3? What if it doesn't?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? That is, what are you getting that you're not expecting? And why do you expect it (as in, given the code you wrote, why would you expect it to work one way instead of the way it's actually working)? Basically the question is, other than us debugging the code for you and just fixing it up and spitting out the answer (which is not what Stack Overflow is for), what specifically are you asking about -- what are you having trouble with?

Comment: @yshavit My code is not splitting up the array equally, the first array is always much more than half of 'password'.

Comment: @Jay `My code is not splitting up the array equally, the first array is always much more than half of 'password'` **Impossible**. With your codes, your first array will always receive the least number of characters. "password" which is length 8 / 3 = 2. It only assign 2 characters to part1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String password = JOptionPane.showinputdialogue("Password: );
final int mid = password.length() / 3;
String[] tokens =
Iterables.toArray(
    Splitter
        .fixedLength(mid)
        .split(password),
    String.class
);
```